# Sublime Text 3 never show console

Tags: console, sublimetext3

Is it possible to hide Sublime Text 3's console for ever?

I don't like the console's look, so I installed 'Buildview' to 'move the console into a view'.

[image: Buildview example]

Unfortunately the console is showing up as well as the Buildview when I build my SCSS.

[image: Console + Buildview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open **`Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Settings-User`** and add the following:

```js
"show_panel_on_build": false
```

Save the file, and you shouldn't see the build pane anymore.